# Firestore timestamp - On passing as props becomes Object

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore

On passing firestore's date timestamp on another Component, the date timestamp becomes an object.

to show the date, all we need is `date.toDate()` but once i passed it to another component, i am not able to display the date by using `date.toDate()`. Because it becomes an object. An object with seconds and nanoseconds.

Why does it happen?
Is that how it should work?

Do i have to convert the seconds to milliseconds and use it in javascript's `new Date` object?

Comment: Please edit the question to show all relevant code that isn't working the way you expect.  It's not clear at all what you mean by "passing to another component".

Comment: I received the date field from firestore in `Component1` and `console.log` shows date field as `timestamp`. When i pass the date field to `Component2` (<Component2 date=this.state.firebase_create_date />) `console.log(this.props.date)` is not a `timestamp` anymore. and i am not able to use `this.props.date.toDate()` function in Component2.

Comment: Please edit the question to show all the relevant code - don't put it in a comment where it's difficult to read.

Comment: okay i will create a sample project for this and i will copy/paste all the code. From my real project, it is related with around 4 components and posting the coding will be more confusing.

Answer (score 1):

When you retrieve a date field from Cloud Firestore, you get a [`Timestamp` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp). To convert that to a regular JavaScript `Date` object, you can call its [`toDate()` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp.html#todate).

So in your example:

```
date.toDate().toDateString()
```

Although I would recommend renaming the variable to `timestamp`, or something similar, to prevent future confusion about its type.

Comment: Yes. I receive date field as `timestamp`.  Can i pass that date field to another component in reactjs? If i do, it automatically becomes an object and `.toDate()` is not possible in that component in which i passed the timestamp

Comment: There is nothing in passing a type of object that converts its type. It's more likely that you're putting the object in the HTML output, which in case of a `Timestamp` may indeed not give you what you expect. Converting a `Date` to a string with its default `toString()` implementation will give a displayable date. But beyond that, it's hard to see much without seeing the [minimal code that reproduces this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as right now we can only speculate on what your code is actually doing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why does timestamp get converted to an object on passing to a component.

Right now i am using the following way to show the date.

```
new Date(date.seconds * 1000).toDateString()
```